# Python bus between processes

Tags: python, robotics

I am completely starting over with my robots brain. All is developed in Python.

I want to keep everything as modular as possible and allow the use of multiple CPU cores (Raspberry PI 2).

I thought of using multiple processes. One for serial communication, one for every sensor, one for every higher function.
All connected by a steering "brain" function.

I want to connect processes by message busses. E.g. Should each sensor dart it's own bus. Higher functions and the brain can then sign in to the bus. In optimal case I would like to send whole objects too.

- Is there a good framework to provide the busses?
- is there maybe a better approach to the whole topic?

Comment: `multiprocessing` ... its a builtin library it has things called `Pipe`'s that do about what you want

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I'll have a look at it. Suggestions for alternatives or abstracting frameworks which make the use easier are welcome.

Comment: I've never had a chance to actually use it, but when looking for similar things, dbus keeps coming up. It has bindings for multiple languages and at least dbus-python seems readily available on raspberry: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusBindings/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [nanomsg](http://nanomsg.org/) (follow-up project to ZeroMQ):

> nanomsg is a socket library that provides several common communication
>   patterns. It aims to make the networking layer fast, scalable, and
>   easy to use. Implemented in C, it works on a wide range of operating
>   systems with no further dependencies.
>
> The communication patterns, also called "scalability protocols", are
>   basic blocks for building distributed systems. By combining them you
>   can create a vast array of distributed applications. The following
>   scalability protocols are currently available:
>
> - PAIR - simple one-to-one communication
> - BUS - simple many-to-many    communication
> - REQREP - allows to build clusters of stateless services    to process user requests
> - PUBSUB - distributes messages to large sets    of interested subscribers
> - PIPELINE - aggregates messages from    multiple sources and load balances them among many destinations
> - SURVEY - allows to query state of multiple applications in a single    go

Comment: Thank. I saw zeromq but didn't see nanomsg. Do you know if python objects came be transported? ( yes, I can read and try it, but maybe you know it by heart ;-) )

Comment: Ah cool. With pickle and nanomsg I have msgbus and sending objects. Thanks.